# three.js shadow cutoff

Tags: html, canvas, webgl, three.js

As the title says.
When i render the current scene everything works fine.
Only the shadow of the white monkey gets cut off.
How can this happen, and is there a resolution for it?

Here is the site: http://hammer.bz/test/
and a screen ;)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jd0h.png

I guess it has to do with the camera or with the lights..
so here are they:

```
renderer.shadowMapEnabled   = true;
renderer.sortObjects = false;
renderer.shadowMapWidth = 3072;
renderer.shadowMapHeight = 3072
renderer.shadowCameraNear = 2;
renderer.shadowCameraFar = 40000;
renderer.shadowCameraFov = 50;
renderer.shadowMapBias = -0.00022;
renderer.shadowMapDarkness = 0.55;
renderer.shadowMapSoft      = true;
renderer.physicallyBasedShading = true;
renderer.setClearColorHex( 0x999999, 1 );


camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 40000 );
camera.position.x = x;
camera.position.y = y;
camera.position.z = z;  
camera.rotation.x = -0.8;
scene.add( camera );


var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1 );
light.position.set( -2, 5, 2 ).normalize();
light.shadowCameraNear  = 0.01;
light.shadowCameraFar   = 1000000;
light.castShadow        = true;
light.shadowDarkness        = 0.5;
light.shadowCameraVisible   = false;
scene.add( light );
```

Thanks in advance!
Bram

EDIT: got it:

just use `THREE.SpotLight` instead.
It was a dumb question.

Just put on `shadowCameraVisible = true;` to see the light and it will work.
Feeling a bit dumb now for this question haha ;)

Comment: Glad you figured it out! Never feel dumb for asking a question with a simple answer. I can't tell you how many times I've figured out my own problems either while in typing out a Stack Overflow question or immediately after posting it. I would recommend actually adding your findings as an answer to this question and then marking it as the accepted answer after the required 24hr wait. That helps others identify that the problem has been solved in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just use `THREE.SpotLight` instead.

Just put on `shadowCameraVisible = true;` to see the light and it will work.
Offcourse you are required to set the position `position.set(x, y, z);`